# BizTalk BRE Utility for Vocabularies

Tags: biztalk, business-rules, biztalk-2016

With BizTalk 2016 FP3 I'm developing a new policy. I'm also creating a vocabulary because this makes the rules easier to read. The problem is, if I create a new version of the vocabulary, the policy continues to reference the old one.

In order to point at the new vocabulary, I need to create a new version of the policy then replace all the references to the vocabulary items. This is very time consuming.

I'm aware of the "re vocabulary" and "re ruleset" tables in the Rule Engine database, and the ability to "unpublish" by setting the "nStatus" value to zero - but this doesn't this particular problem.

I believe there used to be a utility around from Acumen that would solve this problem. Does anyone know if such a utility is still available anywhere?

Comment: Unfortunately asking for a tool is considered off topic for Stackoverflow.   Never heard of that tool before.  Their whole website is offline and has been for a few years.  Can still see it in the Wayback machine  https://web.archive.org/web/20090227024457/http://acumenbusiness.com:80/Products.htm

Comment: The way un-publising, editing and re-publishing solves the problem, is that you don't increase the version number of the vocab.  That way there is no need to re-point the policy to the new vocab.

Comment: Thanks @Dijkgraaf, seems the tool has vanished. This is a shame, since it was praised in Jefford's bible (http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-BizTalk-Server-2006.productCd-0470046422.html), so I think would have been of use. I see your point re vocab versioning but can't help but think the bre composer is not really complete. I often find that my neatly constructed rules, with the complexity abstracted away through vocab entries, are suddenly reduced to the mess of lengthy xpath statements after making minor changes to a rule or vocab.

Comment: Yes, in which case you then have to re-select those changed Vocab items. It is rather painful I agree. Maybe someone will start an open source project to fix this ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the strict versioning of BRE...this, and the lack of 'else' were showstoppers for most use cases.

I got around this with a script that exports and reimports the same Vocabulary in an unpublished state so it can be modified.